# error compiling Objective-C class : Id returned 1 exit status

Tags: objective-c

i tried to compile my first class in Objective-C (Personne.m) and i got the following errors :

```
undefined reference to WinMain@16
Id returned 1 exit status
```

i know that this question was asked before but i still didn`t know how to fix it. THX in advance :)

Comment: More info about your project would be good. Would we be safe in assuming this is a Foundation or Cocoa project with Xcode 3 and the accompanying standard tools? (Because my hunch is that you're doing something much more unusual, the fine details of which are probably very relevant.)

Comment: What compiler and toolchain are you using?  Cygwin GCC?  MinGW?  Something else?

Comment: i am using windows Vista and the the MinGW, i use the command gcc -o className className.m ... command. i read that i should close the application and rebuilt it, i did so but it still bugging, any suggestions, THX.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a `WinMain` function in that file, you probably want to add `-c` to your command line:

```
gcc -c -o className.o className.m
```

Then later, when you're linking together your object files into the final executable, you can leave the `-c` off.  Just make sure one of your object files has `WinMain` in it or that you link against whatever system library is supposed to contain it:

```
gcc -o myApp className.o className2.o ... WinMainLib.a
```